# Unable to Close MySQL database connection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net

I am new to ASP.NET and learning it myself the problem is that I have successfully connected to my database when the page loads I mean when the `Page_Load` method has been called like:

```
MySqlConnection con = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (con == null)
    {
        ConnectDataBase();
    }
}
```

and suppose that it connects successfully when the page loads up! Now I want to close the connection as:

```
  con.Close();
```

so where should I `Close()` it because I am new to this work so I don't know if I can use `Page_Close` method and there I can close the connection.

Can somebody tell me any other good authentic way or idea to do that. The problem is I just want to close the connection!

Comment: Always open and close it where you need it, best by using the `using`-statement. You need to (re-)create the connetion on every postback, since all variables are disposed on the server after the page-lifecycle. You could make it static, but [don't do that](http://tinyurl.com/md4ecdo)! So instead of the field i would use a local variable and create the connection always in the method where i need it. The [`using`-statement](http://tinyurl.com/kv5oeog) closes also the connection, even in case of an error.

Answer (score 5):

You have to close the connection as soon as you are done with it. If you have some code that needs the database, open a connection, get the data, and disconnect.

It is always best to use `using`, since it will close and dispose the connection for you (even when an exception occurs):

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
{
    // open the connection and use it
}

// here it is closed and disposed
```

Answer (score 1):

As Tim said, you should only open it when you need to, and use a `using` statement like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var con = new MySqlConnection(<args>))
    {

    } //at the end of this block, the connection will be Disposed automatically.
}
```